# Setting Properties In Object Array From Array

Tags: arrays, matlab, oop

```
classdef MyObj
   properties
      A;
   end
end
```

%%

```
len = 5;
objArray = MyObj.empty(len,0);
for i=1:len
   objArray(i) = MyObj();
end

dataArray = [1 2 3 4 5];
% How do I set objArray.A to the values in dataArray?
```

Quick question that is basically on Matlab semantics. 
How can I set each `objArray.A` value based on the index in `dataArray` (without looping)?

I have tried multiple variations of `[objArray.A]`, `objArray(:).A`, `objArray.A(:)`, etc. but can't get it working.

PS: The language I'm using is **MATLAB**.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're already using a loop to construct the array, why can't you just set `objArray(i).A = i;` after creating the `ith` object instance?

Comment: @jerad The initialization loop was just for demonstration purposes. In practice, the object array will be initialized elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you're doing, you can assign multiple values to an object array in the following way:

```
values = num2cell(dataArray)
[objArray.A] = values{:}

>> objArray(1).A

ans =

     1

>> objArray(2).A

ans =

     2

>> objArray(3).A

ans =

     3
```

Hope this helps!